# python , run def() multiple times

Tags: python, input

i wrote this code to get Ebay prices
it asks for full ebay link then it writes its price

```
import bs4 , requests
print('please enter full Ebay link  ..')
link = str(input())
def ebayprice(url):
    res = requests.get(link)
    res.raise_for_status()

    txt = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text , 'html.parser')
    csselement = txt.select('#mm-saleDscPrc')
    return csselement[0].text.strip()
price = ebayprice(link)

print('price is : '+ price)
```

i want to improve it and i tried my best and i couldnt
i want it to take multiple links and run them one by one and it should write results each time
it doesnt matter if links are from input() or from links = 'www1,www2,www3'

Comment: use loop statements

Comment: You should replace `res = requests.get(link)` by `res = requests.get(url)`. It currently uses the global link instead of the url provided as argument

Answer (score 1):

you can split by comma and iterate over the `list` using a `for loop`:

```
def ebayprice(url):
    ...

for single_link in link.split(','):
    price = ebayprice(single_link)
    print('price for {} is {}'.format(single_link, price))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want you can ask for how many links, someone want to scrape, and after that you can use for loop statment to go through every url

```
import bs4 , requests
# ask how many links he will pass
print('How many links do you want wo scrape ?')
link_numb = int(input())

# get the links 
print('please enter full Ebay link  ..')
links = [input() for _ in range(link_numb)]

def ebayprice(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    res.raise_for_status()

    txt = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text , 'html.parser')
    csselement = txt.select('#mm-saleDscPrc')
    return csselement[0].text.strip()

for link in links:
    price = ebayprice(link)
    print(price)
```

Example:

```
How many links do you want wo scrape ?
2
please enter full Ebay link  ..
http://example.com
http://example-just-test.com
# simple print the url
http://example.com
http://example-just-test.com
```